# Repeat string into Array in Java

Tags: java

I need to copy the string into a character array the largest number of times you can within the array. In this case OPERATIVO would enter 3 times in the char array and the rest of the array could be whatever character. That I can do?

```
public void copyToArray( char [] arrayCharacters ){
    String var = new String("OPERATIVO");

    for(int i=0 ; i < 30 ; i++){
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Do the size of arrays vary? Or would they vary?

Comment: Always has size 30 the arrayOriginal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure what you want, but I'll give it a shot:

Edit: try this one:

```
public static void copearCaracteres(char[] arrayOriginal )
{
    String cadena = new String("OPERATIVO");
    int div = arrayOriginal.length / cadena.length();
    int j = div * cadena.length();

    for(int i=0 ; i < arrayOriginal.length; i++)
    {
        if(i == j) return;
        arrayOriginal[i] = cadena.charAt(i % cadena.length());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, if only the last 3 should not be modified by not putting the whole word. Output: OPERATIVOOPERATIVOOPERATIVOXGB

Answer (score 1):

```
arrayOriginal.length / cadena.length()
```

will give you the max number of times you can copy the String in the array.

In your case, `30/8 => 3`

Comment: and as I copy to array 3 times?

Comment: @AngelSanchez Use `%` as Martin does in its answer and modify the end condition of your for loop : `for(int i=0 ; i <  arrayOriginal.length / cadena.length() * cadena.length(); i++)`

Answer (score 1):

```
    String cadena = new String("OPERATIVO");
    char[] cad = new char[30];
    int length = cadena.length();
    int count = 1;

    for(int i=0,j=0; i < 30 && j <= length ; i++ ){
        if(j==length)
        {
            j = 0;
            count++;
        }
        if(count > 3)
        {
            break;
        }
        cad[i] = cadena.charAt(j);
        j++;
    }
```

Output : `OPERATIVOOPERATIVOOPERATIVO`

Comment: if only the last 3 should not be modified by not putting the whole word. Output: OPERATIVOOPERATIVOOPERATIVOXGB

Comment: Probably that i < 30 should be arrayOriginal.length.

Comment: you mean to say the char size is 27 @AngelSanchez ??

Comment: No size is always 30. But only copy OPERATIVO while completely into the array.

Comment: @AngelSanchez ohkk gud

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i understand the question correctly, but if you want to copy the `String` to a `character array` then this is how you can do it:

```
public void copy(char[] arr) {
    String string = "Some String";
    if (arr.length < string.length())
        // error
    arr = string.toCharArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.lang.System.arraycopy()`:

```java
String srcString = "OPERATIVO";
char[] srcArray = srcString.toCharArray();
int maxLength = 30;
char[] destArray = new char[maxLength];
int pos = 0;
while(pos < maxLength) {
  java.lang.System.arraycopy(srcArray, 
                             0, 
                             destArray, 
                             pos, 
                             Math.min(srcArray.length, maxLength - pos));
  pos += srcArray.length;
}
String string = new String(destArray);
System.out.println(string);
```